# is there a way to set the height of dropdown to show only 10 values at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, height, drop-down-menu

is there a way to control the height of dropdown box? i have like 200 items in the dropdown but want to display only 10 at a time so that it will not show 20-30 values at a time..

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to add, a size attribute :

```
<select size="10">

</select>
```

Comment: If you specify a size greater that 1, then the select will be rendered as a listbox instead of a dropdown.

Comment: yeah, size attribute doesn't help because it convert it into listbox which is not my intention...i want to use dropdown but when you click on dropdown should show only 10 values instead of 20-30 values...this values differ from browser to browser...so this question is still open

Comment: @ElianEbbing Awesome point..i was thinking what's happening to dropdown after adding size attribute to it dynamically :P..lolzzz +1 for you..i wish i could vote up more... :)